# Angular, firing event in nested repeat on a $last

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a nested ng-repeat in which I am trying to fire an event. so I have something like

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <div ng-repeat="prop in item.props"> {{prop.name}}</div>
  </div>
```

So what I would like to have happen is an event to fire once the last prop in the last item has been rendered.

So My first idea was to put the logic in a directive with restrict="C" and do something like

```
 ng-class=“{ fix-directive : prop.$parent.$last && prop.$last}”
```

where fix-directive is the directive with the logic i want fired. Is something like this possible? Or maybe there is perhaps a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fire a directive after the last element has been rendered, you will have to add a condition to the directive;

```
    .directive('repeat-element',['$timeout','$http',function($timeout,$http) {
                        return {
                            restrict : 'A',
                            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                                if (scope.$last === true) {
                                    $timeout(function() {
                                        //timeout so that it is called when everything gets rendered
                                        doStuff(scope.items);
                                    });
                                }
                                //rest of the code

....................
```

this was how I did that, so you can just add more condition like `parent.$last` is also true.

This should do your work